# JQuery full screen only working on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullscreen

I'm trying to force an auto fullscreen (later this will be only on mobile devices)
I'm using a fullscreen plugin from [kayahr](https://github.com/kayahr/jquery-fullscreen-plugin) and with the following code

```
$('#videoPlayer').on('loadedmetadata', function () {
    $("#videoPlayer").fullScreen(true); // 1
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#videoPlayer").fullScreen(true); // 2
    }, 3000);
});

$('#fullscreen').on('click', function () {
    $("#videoPlayer").fullScreen(true); // 3
});
```

`1`, `2` are getting called, but nothing happens.
but when I press the button linked to `3`, the fullscreen get's called like it should.

Any clue why? my only toughs are that the browser doesn't want you to auto call full screen without a users input.

Comment: Few questions : why do you call twice the `.fullScreen()` method on your first event handler ? And did you tried to use *CSS* instead ?

Comment: is `videoPlayer` a `<video>` element?

Comment: The videoPlayer is a video element, and I call it twice for testing, once directly when the video is loaded and once when after some time out (maybe the video wasn't loaded yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Fullscreen requests need to be called from within an event handler or otherwise they will be denied.

says the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode).

So, you cannot initiate fullscreen from timeout or any other method. You have to request fullscreen from an JS event handler in order to make it work. No custom event handlers should work if they are not based on native Events.

Hope it helps.